# Python: comprehension to compose two dictionaries

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a comprehension that will compose two dictionaries in the following way:

```
d1 = {1:'a',2:'b',3:'c'}
d2 = {'a':'A','b':'B','c':'C'}
result = {1:'A',2:'B',3:'C'}
```

That is, the resulting dictionary is formed from the keys of the first one and the values of the second one for each pair where the value of the first one is equal to the key of the second one.

This is what I've got so far:

```
{ k1:v2 for (k1,v1) in d1 for (k2,v2) in d2 if v1 == k2 }
```

but it doesn't work. I'm new to Python so I'm not sure whether this really makes sense. I'm using python 3.3.2 by the way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks to everyone, wish I could accept more than one.

Comment: If you don't insist on using comprehension, refer to my answer to a very related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71428241/6087087

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way to do it is:

```
result = {k: d2.get(v) for k, v in d1.items()}
```

What behavior did you want for keys that have a value that is not in d2?

Comment: +1 for not crashing when `d2` doesn't have a key for some value in `d1`.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks a lot. I have a fixed set of inputs, which I know have that format, so it's fine if I leave that behavior unspecified.

Comment: Just to be explicit - the above will give any unmatched keys the value `None`.  To omit unmatched keys, you'd use `{k: d2[v] for k, v in d1.items() if v in d2}`

Answer (score 6):

Just loop through the items of `d1` and then for each element you want to put in the result don’t use the value from `d1` but instead look up the new value within `d2` using `d1`’s value as the key:

```
>>> d1 = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
>>> d2 = {'a': 'A', 'b': 'B', 'c': 'C'}
>>> d = {k: d2[v] for (k, v) in d1.items()}
>>> d
{1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C'}
```

Answer (score 2):

This way works even if not all values in `d1` are valid keys for `d2`:

```
 {k1:d2[d1[k1]] for k1 in d1 if d1[k1] in d2}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
This is what I've got so far:

    { k1:v2 for (k1,v1) in d1 for (k2,v2) in d2 if v1 == k2 }
```

Two things you should note:

1) When you use a for-in loop directly on a dict:

```
for (k1, v1) in some_dict:
```

python loops over the keys in the dict, i.e that for-in loop is equivalent to:

```
for (k1, v1) in some_dict.keys()
```

But you are telling python that there will be a two tuple returned each time through the loop, (k1, v1), and python only returns a key each time through the loop.  So that is an error.  You can correct that by writing:

```
for (k1, v1) in some_dict.items()
```

The items() function returns a two tuple:  (key, value) each time through the loop.

2) Suppose you have this data:

```
data = [ 
    [1, 2, 3], 
    ['a', 'b', 'c']
]
```

To loop over each of the six values, it feels natural to write:

```
results = [x for x in inner_array for inner_array in data]
```

But that produces the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 5, in <module>
    results = [x for x in inner_array for inner_array in data]
NameError: name 'inner_array' is not defined
```

To make it work, the loops have to be written "backwards":

```
results = [x for inner_array in data for x in inner_array]
print results

--output:--
[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

I think the easiest way to remember that is: the loops are in the same order as if you wrote them without a list comprehension:

```
results = [] 

for inner_array in data:
    for x in inner_array:
        results.append(x)
```

Personally, I would like to see that changed in python, so that inside a list/dict/set comprehension you work from "the inside out", like you wrote it.  In any case, this is what your code looks like with the changes:

```
d1 = {1:'a',2:'b',3:'c'}
d2 = {'a':'A','b':'B','c':'C'}

results = {
        k1: v2 
        for (k2,v2) in d2.items() 
        for (k1,v1) in d1.items() if v1 == k2 
}

print results

--output:--
{1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C'}
```

Comment: @Roma149, It might be helpful to check out my explanation of what you did wrong when writing your dict comprehension.

Comment: Wow, outstanding explanation, I really appreciate it. It seems that my version did make some sense after all :)