# Stuck defining composition function in python

Tags: python, composition

input: two functions f and g, represented as dictionaries, such that g ◦ f exists. output: dictionary that represents the function g ◦ f. 
example: given f = {0:’a’, 1:’b’} and g = {’a’:’apple’, ’b’:’banana’}, return {0:’apple’, 1:’banana’}.

The closest to the correct answer I have is with {i:g[j] for i in f for j in g} which outputs {0: 'apple', 1: 'apple'}. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: comprehension to compose two dictionaries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846545/python-comprehension-to-compose-two-dictionaries)

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are great, but they create an entire dictionary which may be slow. If you only want a read-only composition, then the following class will solve your problems:

```
class Composition_mapping(collections.abc.Mapping):
    
    def __init__(self, f, g):
        self.f = f
        self.g = g
    
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.g)
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.g)
        
    def keys(self):
        return self.g.keys()
    
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.f[self.g[item]]
```

For example:

```
a = {1: 5}

b = {5:9, 7 : 8}

c = Composition_mapping(b,a)

print(c[1])

>>> 9
```

If you decide to make it a dict, you can always do:

```
c = dict(c)
print(c)
>>> {1: 9}
```

This is safe, because Composition_mapping satisfies [the mapping protocol](https://docs.python.org/3.3/glossary.html#term-mapping), which means it is considered as a mapping. A mapping is an interface (protocol) for read-only dictionary-like structures. Note that it is not necessary to inherit from collections.abc.Mapping, you just need to implement the methods `__getitem__, __iter__, __len__  __contains__, keys, items, values, get, __eq__, and __ne__` to be a mapping; after all Python favors duck typing. The reason my code inherits from collections.abc.Mapping is that it implements all the other methods for you except `__getitem__, __iter__, __len__`. See  [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.abc.html) for the details about protocols.

Creating a composition with this method will have constant time cost no matter how big the composed functions are. The look-ups can be a little bit slower due to double look-ups and extra function call, but you can always use `c = dict(c)` if you are going to make lots of calls in a performance critical part. More importantly, if you change a and b anywhere in your code, the changes will be reflected on c.

Answer (score 0):

You need to just iterate over one dict `f`, and in the comprehension, replace the value of f with the value of `g`

```
f = {0:'a', 1:'b'}
g = {'a':'apple', 'b': 'banana'}
new_dict = {k: g[v] for k, v in f.items()}
# Value of new_dict = {0: 'apple', 1: 'banana'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct dict comprehension would be:

```
{i:g[f[i]] for i in f}
```

You did:

```
{i:g[j] for i in f for j in g}
```

That mapped every i to every `i` to every value in `g`, but then dict removed duplicate keys.

To see what is going on, try generating a list instead:

```
>>> [(i, g[j]) for i in f for j in g]
[(0, 'apple'), (0, 'banana'), (1, 'apple'), (1, 'banana')]
```

In the correct case:

```
>>> [(i, g[f[i]]) for i in f]
[(0, 'apple'), (1, 'banana')]
```